# Convert CSV to XML by LXML & Pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, lxml

I'm working on a project that I need to convert a csv to XML. I had the following code works fine, but the result isn't what I'm looking for and I wonder if anyone can point out which method I'm missing.

So my csv pandas dataframe lookalike:

```
  a b c d
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
```

and the code:

```
xmlroot = lxml.etree.Element("root")
for row in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
    current = lxml.etree.Element('project')
    xmlroot.append(current)
    for col, value in row.items():
        current.set(col, value)
with open('final.xml', 'wb') as filepath:
    filepath.write(lxml.etree.tostring(xmlroot, pretty_print=True))
```

The output is:

```
<root>
  <project a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4/>
</root>
```

but I want something looks like:

```
<root>
  <project>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
    <d>4</d>
  </project>
</root>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html):

```
df.to_xml('final.xml', index=False, root_name='root', row_name='project')
```

Output:

```
>>> %cat 'final.xml'
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <project>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
    <d>4</d>
  </project>
  <project>
    <a>2</a>
    <b>3</b>
    <c>4</c>
    <d>5</d>
  </project>
  <project>
    <a>3</a>
    <b>4</b>
    <c>5</c>
    <d>6</d>
  </project>
</root>
```